# Jenkins Log On Account user - Can it be changed?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

Jenkins is configured to run with Jenkins Service Log On Account user: Domain1\User1

My job runs the command: 
echo %USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME%

And it prints:  Domain1\User1

Now I change the Jenkins Service Log On Account user: Domain1\User2

Restart Jenkins service.

Run the job again, but it still prints: Domain1\User1

Why the %USERNAME% isn't refreshed?

Comment: What name is shown next to the jenkins service in 'Windows services'?

Answer (score 0):

The `%USERNAME%` environment variable shows the username of who runs the jenkins service, not that one, who is currently logged in.

Comment: I meant, even when changing the Jenkins Service Log On Account user, it still prints the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I've found some bug reports regarding this issue:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27739
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27739

Should be solved in Jenkins version  1.617